# What do you call it when the meaning of a word changes within a sentence?

Tags: terminology

Here's an example from "The Hill We Climb," by Amanda Gorman (the poem that she read at Pres. Biden's inauguration):  "We lay down our arms so we can reach out our arms."  The meaning of "arms" changes from the first to the second appearances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [**antanaclasis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis) (OED: "The same word is repeated in a different, if not a contrary signification"; Merriam-Webster: "the repetition of a word within a phrase or sentence in which the second occurrence utilizes a different and sometimes contrary meaning from the first"), with many other examples provided at the link.

Comment: Technically, she used unrelated word, as *arms* and *arms* sound alike and are spelled alike.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, would that make them homonyms?

Comment: Yes, they are both homonyms and homophones.